# preg_replace and combination of '[', ']' and '/' for replacement

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to use preg_replace for combination of '[', ']' and '/' but I could'nt find the right way!

I have these strings:

```
$str = "This is a [u]PHP[/u] test . This is second[/u] test.
 This [u]is another [u]test[/u].";

$url = "http://www.test.com";
```

In result I want to have :

```
str1 = "This is a <a href='http://www.test.com'>PHP</a> test . 
 This is second[/u] test.
This <a href='http://www.test.com'>is another [u]test</a>.";
```

and also [u]=[U], [/u]=[/U] are case insensitive.

Comment: You can't balance tags with preg_replace.

Comment: … not with `preg_replace` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no opening square brackets inside the `[u]` tags:

```
preg_replace('~\[u\]([^[]+)\[/u\]~i', '<a href="'.$url.'">$1</a>', $str);
```

The regular expression explained:

- `~` is used as delimiter to avoid [leaning slash syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)
- `\[` and `\]` match literal square brackets
- `(` and `)` denote a capture group which in the replacement string is `$1`
- `[^[]+` matches anything but an opening square bracket once or more
- `i` modifier makes the regular expression case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Well,i think what you want is

```
$str = "This is a [u]PHP[/u] test . This is second[/u] test.
 This [u]is another [u]test[/u].";

$url = "http://www.test.com";

echo preg_replace('#\[u\]((?:(?!\[/u\]).)*)\[/u\]#is',"<a href='{$url}'>\\1</a>",$str);
```

`((?:(?!\[/u\]).)*)` means it would match some characters which don't including string '[/u]'

Answer (score 1):

```
$str1 = preg_replace('#\[(u|U)\](.*?)(?=\[/\1)\[/\1\]#', "<a href='http://www.test.com'>$2</a>", $str);
var_dump($str, $str1);
```

Output

```
string(85) "This is a [u]PHP[/u] test . This is second[/u] test.
 This [u]is another [u]test[/u]."
string(139) "This is a <a href='http://www.test.com'>PHP</a> test . This is second[/u] test.
 This <a href='http://www.test.com'>is another [u]test</a>."
```